# How would I go about developing an interface that would allow integration of 6 other models?

Tags: interfaces, integration, development

I am new to programming, I have been trying to get my head around this.

**Context**

My project is about defining investment packages for various construction projects within a country based around an economy model. There are 5 regional models, and I am writing about a company working on the interface that will allow integration of the 5 regional models with the national economy model that will allow financial decision making.

**Question**

How would I go about developing an interface that would allow integration of 6 other models? Would someone be able to provide a basic overview of the interface development method?

Comment: Hi @user295188 for us to give valuable answers, it would be good some more context. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more the situation? Right now, the question is either too broad and unclear what are you asking.

Comment: Hi Laiv, my project is about defining investment packages for various construction projects within a country based around an economy model. There are 5 regional models, and I am writing about a company working on the interface that will allow integration of the 5 regional models with the national economy model that will allow financial decision making. Would you be able to provide a basic overview of the interface development method? Apologies, I'm not sure if I am asking the right questions here.

Comment: I have edited the question. Since you have introduced some hints about the *domain* (economical) I hope it could pull the attention of users with a background on the subject. If you find that something else worth to be mentioned, please, edit the question.